# Extending ember data fields possible?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

So lets say I have something like (in model):

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  status: attr('string'),
});
```

API returns following values for `status`: `pending`, `delivered`, `completed`. 
In the Ember app, if `status` == `delivered`. The value should instead be rendered as `arrived`.

Which means, in the model, I have a CP:

```
refinedStatus: Ember.computed('status', {
  get() {
    if (this.get('status') == 'delivered') {
      return 'arrived';
    }

    else {
      return this.get('status');
    }
  }
}),
```

I also dont like the fact, that I need to create a new CP called `refinedStatus`, which literally does the same thing, but only having one condition.

Is there a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 3):

create transform using the command

```
ember generate transform refined-status
```

**refined-status.js** override deserialize method to convert server response to your required format.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    if(serialized === 'delivered') {
     return 'arrived' 
    } else {
     return serialized;
    }
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }
});
```

mention this transform in model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  status: attr('refined-status'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeAttribute` in the serializer (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#method_serializeAttribute)

```
serializeAttribute(snapshot, json, key, attribute) {
  if (key === "status") {
    if (snapshot.attr(key) === 'delivered') 
      json[key] = 'arrived';
    } else {
      json[key] = snapshot.attr(key)
    }
  } else {
    this._super(snapshot, json, key, attribute);
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting `Error while processing route: products.index Cannot read property 'type' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined